# Error: 'object' is not an exported object from 'namespace:package'?

Tags: r

I am using a package called `{butteR}` and a function called `butteR::closest_distance_rtree()` to match coordinates with their closest known settlement. The code looks like this:

```
# install.packages("devtools")
# devtools::install_github("zackarno/butteR")

matched_coordinates <- butteR::closest_distance_rtree(coordinates, master_settlement_list)
```

Should be simple enough, but I keep getting the following error:

```
Error: 'knn.RTree' is not an exported object from 'namespace:rtree'
```

I've re-installed both `{butteR}` and `{rtree}`, checked the namespace for `{rtree}`, re-started R and cleared the environment, and checked for typos. Any ideas would be appreciated!

Comment: Where did you get the `butteR` package?  It's not on CRAN.  This looks like a bug in that package.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond! I'll add the link below. butteR is on GitHub, and it's made specifically for working with data from mobile data collection systems like ODK. https://github.com/zackarno/butteR

Comment: There aren't any updates since May 2021, and there is a very basic error in the package:  it imports from `rTree` without declaring it will do so, and it tries to use a function that `rTree` doesn't export.  I would look for a different package that is on CRAN:  the basic tests it does would have prevented this error.  Alternatively, you could fork `butteR`, and fix all the errors yourself.

Comment: Roger Bivand is using `dbscan` within `spdep` currently but hoped this would be faster. I would imagine that, upon forking, there is a little more involved than updating Description to mention `r.tree`, @user2554330, might you expand just a little.

Comment: @Chris, I don't see much more to add.  There are basic errors in that package.  It is not finished.  Don't use it.

Comment: At a colleague's recommendation, I decided to use the nn2() function from the RANN package (https://github.com/jefferislab/RANN) as an alternative. It works fine for finding nearest neighbor, which is all I needed the function to do. Resolved! Thanks